# How to use session in PHP with variables

Tags: php, session

I am new in PHP. I want to use session with variable. Its my first experience to play with session. I create 4 pages.

**1. is session1.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
$_SESSION['UserID']='1';
?>
```

**2. is session.php**

```
<?php

 // starts session
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['UserID']='1')
{
    header("location: user.php");
    }
    if($_SESSION['UserID']='2')
{
    header("location: mang.php");
    }
?>
```

**3.user.php**

```
<?php

echo "This is User page";
?>
```

**4.mang.php**

```
<?php
echo "This is manager page";
?>
```

In my code there is problem of IF condition. My IF condition is not working. Can you guys please help to sort out my problem.

Comment: It's usually helpful when you say "my (blank) is not working" if you explain what it is or isn't doing; If it's giving an error, tell us the error!

Comment: @DaymonSchroeder Below is answer of my question. I sort out my problem from that answer

Comment: In **IF** you have to use Comparison operator not assignment operator  change `$_SESSION['UserID']='2'` to `$_SESSION['UserID']=='2'`

Comment: Your problem occurred because of a typo.

Comment: @sunny , Please mark the answer as accepted so the other users can identify the correct answer easily :)

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Stackoverflow said to wait for couple of minute after i will mark as accept your answer. Thank you so much

Comment: @sunny , hey that's OK , glad to help :)

Comment: You will never go to mang.php

Comment: @DinukaDayarathna , Yes he will never go because he is setting UserID to 1 manually  . :) . think a situation that he generates the UserID dynamically, in that situation the code will work fine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
if($_SESSION['UserID']='1') and if($_SESSION['UserID']='2')
```

to

```
if($_SESSION['UserID']=='1') and if($_SESSION['UserID']=='2')
```

And also you have started session in `session1.php` , so no need to start the session again in `session.php`

Final Output

```
<?php

 include ("session1.php");

 if($_SESSION['UserID']=='1')
 {
    header("location: user.php");
    exit;
 }
 if($_SESSION['UserID']=='2')
 {
    header("location: mang.php");
    exit;
 }
```